# Preamble for Conferences

Tags: preamble

I want a preamble that encompasses all the major conferences in computer science. The purpose is to include that preamble with some keyword representing the conference and no other effort is required in terms of class, style and bibliography. Is there any such preamble available online that can be used for all major conferences like LNCS, SIAM, IEEE?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: I thought that's what `\documentclass` was for ?